# Open source GUI tool for data wrangling with little or no programming

Tags: open-source, data-analysis, data

A programming-challenged analyst has data like this:

```
ID          NAME    DATE
SYSID-1054  XYZ     1
SYSID-1054  XYZ     2
SYSID-1054  OPQ     3
SYSID-1054  OPQ     4
SYSID-1054  XYZ     5
SYSID-1054  XYZ     6
SYSID-1054  XYZ     7
SYSID-1055  ABC     8
SYSID-1055  ABC     9
SYSID-1055  DEF     10
SYSID-1055  DEF     11
```

The goal is finding records where `NAME` changes from day to day for the same `ID`, output should be this:

```
ID          NAME    DATE
SYSID-1054  XYZ     1
SYSID-1054  OPQ     3
SYSID-1054  XYZ     5
SYSID-1055  ABC     8
SYSID-1055  DEF     10
```

Yes, I know that in SQL/some programming language this is simple to do. I'm looking for a GUI-based tool for the analyst who's unable/is not willing to learn programming who still wants to construct data processing pipeline in the app that can compute results like this.

So far I've looked at [Orange](https://orange.biolab.si/), but have been unable to get result like this in the app (perhaps it's because I know little how to use it for now), but am also looking for alternatives.

Can `KNIME` do this?

Please recommend some tool that can transform data like this without writing code or with writing little code.

Comment: I've played with KNIME and I think it can do what you want. It takes a bit of learning to use however.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [**OpenRefine**](http://openrefine.org/).

You first need to add a new column based on the `ID` and `NAME` columns, e.g. using this expression:
`cells["ID"].value + ";" + cells["NAME"].value`

Sorting by the new column, using the "Blank down" feature and then creating a "Facet by blank" allows you to remove the duplicate `ID`+`NAME` combinations.